# Deleting GPS points outside of polygon using QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I am using QGIS 3.16.

I have created a layer which is a polygon for my "study area".  I have 2 datasets that have been provided to me containing GPS co-ordinates which I have added as 2 separate layers - 1 of these is in British National Grid, and the other is in long/lat.  I want to now remove any points from these datasets that fall outside my study area, but am unsure how.  There are 400+ records combined, and there are more outside my area than inside.

Comment: Want you want is the clip tool in QGIS under Vector Overlay in the processing toolbox.

Comment: You might also need to transform your layers into the same coordinate system.  To do that, use Reproject Layer under Vector General in the toolbox.

Comment: Perfect, thanks so much!